# Adjacent selectInput in Shiny and ShinySemantic

Tags: r, shiny

I have created this module for two selectInput:

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.semantic)

my_inputs_UI <- function(id, values) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  all_types <- unique(values)
  tagList(
      selectInput(inputId = ns("this_type"),
                  label = "Select this type",
                  choices = all_types),
      selectInput(inputId = ns("this_name"),
                  label = "Select this name",
                  choices = list())
  )
}

my_inputs_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
    }
  )
}
```

So these two selectInput appear one above the other. My question is, is it possible for these two to be adjacent?

I have tried this, using a div but they still appear one above the other:

```
my_inputs_UI <- function(id, values) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  all_types <- unique(values)
  tagList(
    div(
      selectInput(inputId = ns("this_type"),
                  label = "Select this type",
                  choices = all_types),
      br(),
      selectInput(inputId = ns("this_name"),
                  label = "Select this name",
                  choices = list()))
  )
}
```

Please, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `{shiny.semantic}` then I'd recommend using Semantic UI classes for consistency:

```r
shiny.semantic::form(
  shiny.semantic::fields(
    class = "two",
    shiny.semantic::field(
      selectInput(
        inputId = ns("this_type"),
        label = "Select this type",
        choices = all_types
      )
    ),
    shiny.semantic::field(
      selectInput(
        inputId = ns("this_name"),
        label = "Select this name",
        choices = list()
      )
    )
  )
)
```

[image: Two Semantic UI dropdowns side by side]

There's more about structuring input forms [here](https://fomantic-ui.com/collections/form.html).

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer @Ashley Baldry, just a question, `shiny.semantic::field` depends on the class = `"two"` to be 2 adjacent columns, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that’s correct :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fluidRow` and `column`.  Try this

```
my_inputs_UI <- function(id, values) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  values <- c(LETTERS[1:6])
  all_types <- unique(values)
  tagList(
    fluidRow(
      column(3,
             selectInput(inputId = ns("this_type"),
                         label = "Select this type",
                         choices = all_types)
      ),
      column(4,
             selectInput(inputId = ns("this_name"),
                         label = "Select this name",
                         choices = list())
      )
    )
  )
}
```

[image: output]